# Is it possible to get 4 digit unique number in moble phone

Tags: android

I would like to get unique ID from mobile phone.I know IMEI code is unique but it is too long for me.I only want to get most 4 unique digit in mobile phone information.

Comment: Should this be unique across all the devices who has installed your app?

Comment: Use a hash function and IMEI as argument. However, I wonder why only 4 digits...

Comment: Even using a hash on one of the long unique numbers you're _guaranteed_ to have duplicates after the first 9999 devices. In reality, you may get a duplicate on the 2nd device. So you'll need an approach to handle collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Android id is a unique String. You can use that.

Other way is using MAC. MAC address is also unique.It is 48bit lenghth.
Use below method to get MAC.

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress();
```

If you want exactly 4 digit, you can use any commonly available hash algorithm.